# Convert Excel to GeoJson in Java

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, json

I'm looking for a way to convert an Excel file to a GeoJson file, I looked at GeoTools, found an gt-excel plugin, but I couldn't get it through Maven to try it out. 
Is there another way ?

**edit**

The excel file format may vary, but it always does contain a 'lon' and 'lat' fields.

Here is an example :

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot showing how your Excel sheet is formatted? Thanks!

Comment: Try, Apache POI to read the excel data into your java class and convert your java object to JSON formatted data using Jackson-JSON API. Sounds like you need lot of coding skills. But that's just my idea as you have tagged java in your question.